# New breed of spam?

Tags: discussion, support, spam, grace-period

I just noticed a new-to-me tactic for spammers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219197) (probably gone by the time I post this). It seemed to be originally a LQ question, then within seconds of me asking for clarification/marking to close, it became a super spammy post.

Do we have any defenses against that such as detecting significant question/post editing in a short window (especially by new users)?

I'm concerned that the spammers might be gaming with our mod stats now especially around improper close reasons (due to the edit being masked)

Comment: Yep, the bots are "evolving"; presumably whomever is behind them is seeing how community reacts to their spam and what countermeasures [so] are implementing, and so the methods to get around those measures is becoming more clever. Though I hate the spam, I feel that you can't fault the ingenuity...

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  We're aware of the issue and working on defenses.  This is a perfectly fine question, but I'm going to delete it to avoid giving attentive spammers any more good ideas about tactics.

Comment: The spreeders are bamming

Comment: Why do they even bother when we have such extremely effective measures? They already have (almost) free reign in YouTube comments and elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterMortensen stack overflow is heavily indexed by Google. So their spam even shows there

Comment: Note, posting a unclear question and then editing the spam in is not new. On AU we had those.

Comment: AU = *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*

Comment: @DanielA.White Google can index within the 5 minutes or so that the post would be up without creating a revision? I've always known Google to take longer than that to notice a page change.

Comment: What's the motivation for this? Is this so the preview text on `/questions` looks un spammy?

Comment: @PeterMortensen gold, thanks ;)

Comment: @MartinSmith one hunch I have is that they might want to harm our moderation stats so that less people have power to do something?

Comment: FYI, this type of spam has been [known since at least 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/questions/476) (requires Charcoal team access).

Comment: @DanielA.White I've noticed that such spam questions are deleted almost immediately by the bot. Is this short time window enough for those questions to be indexed by Google?

Comment: Ironically, at almost exactly the same time as SE rolled out their change which doesn't permit an edit grace period to users with < 10 reputation, I submitted a PR for SmokeDetector which allows SmokeDetector to detect grace period edits. The PR was merged a bit later. So, while the need to detect grace period edits is *much* lower now, SmokeDetector does do so for all posts by all users, as of about 3 months ago.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Good news: we do now have such a defense!

Users lacking the [remove new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) can no longer make edits that don't create a revision in the post history.  This will greatly aid in detection of such abuse and ought to result in much faster removal of these posts.

Comment: thanks for reopening this. I hope it does help!

Comment: I'm glad this was implemented. I've been actually been noticing this spam tactic for a little over a week now and was waiting for some kind of defense mechanism.

Comment: [This change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/21789/revisions)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Sadly it's not clear what exactly the change is. Users with less than 10 rep can't edit until five minutes pass, or does the change mean that there is new revision created for every edit they make? SE should really be more transparent with such changes, it's annoying they are so far from it. Even when they do tell about changes, they're super vague and give no details. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar This isn't vague though. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/21789/revisions, as linked earlier -- the grace period can no longer be used by users with less than 10 rep. This doesn't mean they can't edit for five minutes, it means a new revision is made for every change. Those are auditable and detectable by bots, but at the expense of a more noisy revision history for legitimate users. That's definitely a price worth paying at the current volume of spam, however.

Comment: @Zoe well vague for me, "can't use grace period" can easily mean edits locked until grace period over.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Says No More War: Agreed. It could be made much clearer.

Comment: Hwo did you get this to happen? CM contact?

Comment: @richardec basically, yeah. Charcoal and the SO moderators have been in contact with the CM team throughout the spam wave to figure out ways to thwart them.